# Any example to use giflossy library create gif file in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, gif

My current attempt:

```
Gif_Stream* gfs = Gif_NewStream();
gfs->screen_width = 640;
gfs->screen_height = 480;

Gif_Colormap *cm = Gif_NewFullColormap(216, 256);
Gif_Color *col = cm->col;
for (int i = 0; i < 216; i++) {
    col[i].gfc_red = (i / 36) * 0x33;
    col[i].gfc_green = ((i / 6) % 6) * 0x33;
    col[i].gfc_blue = (i % 6) * 0x33;
}
gfs->global = cm;

// load image
...
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    Gif_Image* gfi = Gif_NewImage();

    // set width/height
    gfi->width = imgW;
    gfi->height = imgH;

    Gif_SetUncompressedImage(gfi, pixelPtr, Gif_Free, 0);

    Gif_AddImage(gfs, gfi);
}

FILE* f = fopen("test.gif", "w");
Gif_WriteFile(gfs, f);
fclose(f);
```

result (Just a screen shot): [image]just get some error color in top.
There is no simple example in https://github.com/pornel/giflossy.

Comment: What is your expected output? (i / 36) * 0x33; looks like random noise as can be seen in your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even without a simple example, the github link you provided does contain all the [example code](https://github.com/pornel/giflossy/blob/master/src/gifsicle.c#L893) you should need to get this working.

I would start by changing

```
FILE* f = fopen("test.gif", "w");
```

to:

```
FILE* f = fopen("test.gif", "wb");
```

Comment: tks, "wb" is right. now I need to know how to put my pixel into gif. gifsicle.c has too many function, and i havnt found where to convert my image into gif_stream.